# Receiving/Responding Gmail in Python Server (SMTP or Some Other Format)

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

I know that SMTP server can receive/send Gmail messages and I have seen some examples online including Stack Overflow. Is there a way for you to send a message from a real Gmail account to a smtp server in python and have it decode the message into plain text/a string?